# Why is Resharper only finding usages in certain projects?

Tags: resharper

I've recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2015 and things have been ok sofar with the exception of Find Usages in Resharper. When looking for usages of a particular method it only seems to display usages in test projects but not in other projects where the method is clearly used. I've been looking through the Resharper options to try and find out if something is configured strangely but with no success.

Any ideas? Find Usages has always worked fine for me and it would seem strange for it to default to find usages in only a subset of the projects in a solution. Note that this is not just restricted to methods, it's find usages for pretty much anything.

Comment: I had a similar problem, but without upgrading or changing anything in my development environment. Suddenly, I just noticed that R# was only showing the 2 usages of a method in tests, but not the actual single use by the other code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was shown a solution to this problem this morning which is quite simple. Just clear the Resharper cache. To do this, in visual studio do the following:

Resharper -> Options -> Environment -> General

There should be a button in the Caches section 'Clear Caches'
Click on this and then restart Visual Studio.

Comment: You should accept your own answer. Thanks for the fix, I ran into the issue as well with ReSharper 2018.1. Your answer is also [suggested as a workaround](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206412869-Find-usages-not-working-in-Visual-Studio-2015-after-installing-Active-Reports) by ReSharper.